# angularjs ng-option concantinate

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have the following ng-options script:

```
ng-options="option.flsName for option in vm.brgFilterDataOptions"
```

I want to concantinate to have it like this:

```
ng-options="option. + '{{record.field}}' + for option in vm.brgFilterDataOptions"
```

is that possible?

Comment: Maybe just `option[record.field] for option in vm.brgFilterDataOptions` ..?

Comment: Thanks.  That would work :)

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, since you can't interpolate ({{}}) inside an expression, but you can call a function in the controller and get the result:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-options="getVal(option) as getVal(option) for option in options" ng-model="val"></select>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getVal = function (val) {
    return val + ' is working';
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18884/)

Answer (score 0):

Just access the object's property without dot notation.
`option[record.field] for option in vm.brgFilterDataOptions`